# Add id to element with jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, element, addition

I have a HTML `button` and I want to add an `id` to the element. However I'm not able to do it manually, so I'm looking for an option through jQuery.

```
<div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play">
  <button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button> 
</div>
```

Comment: But what's the use of adding `id` after the page is loaded? Looks like an XY problem to me.

Comment: This is 100% pointless. If you can select the element in order to put an `id` on it, then you don't need to put an `id` on it as you have already selected it...

Comment: *"I have a HTML button and I want to add an id to the element."* Why? Sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me...

Comment: While this is likely an XY problem, there *are* situations where you might want to add an `id` after the element is created. For instance, if you're creating the elements from HTML text, but the `id` information is coming from an insecure source. In that case, you do want to add the `id` using DOM manipulation (probably just after creating the element, but before adding it to the DOM). You would do so because changing it in the HTML text, prior to creation, would be a security hole.

Comment: For example: `let id='from-insecure-source';let newDiv = $('<div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play"><button type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button></div>'); newDiv.find('button').attr('id', id);` is secure, whereas `let newDiv = $('<div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play"><button ' + id + 'type="button" aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button></div>');` is not. If someone is trying to get code to run, the former might end up with an invalid ID, but the code won't be run.

Comment: @Makyen Oh wow.

Comment: Adding an ID on the fly is useful when you are adding an element on the fly.  Of course you know where it is when you are adding it...but knowing where it is at a different time could be problematical.  With a unique ID, it's a no-brainer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with jQuery using `prop()` or `attr()` method :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button.mejs-play button').prop('id', 'my-id');
    //Or 
    $('.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button.mejs-play button').attr('id', 'my-id');
});
```

```js
$('.mejs-button button').prop('id', 'my-id');

console.log( $('.mejs-button button').prop('id') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mejs-button mejs-playpause-button mejs-play"><button type="button" 
aria-controls="mep_0" title="Play" aria-label="Play" tabindex="0"></button> 
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure if prop works here. Did you check this?

Comment: Sure check my working snippet

Comment: If the `.mejs-button` have multiple buttons, then this would fail

Comment: Yes, but it's not the case here (I think)

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman - Yes, `prop` works just fine. `id` is a pure reflected property.

Comment: This isn't technically wrong, but it's definitely not the right approach to whatever problem the OP is trying to solve.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks! `:)`

Comment: @MohammedAcharki it is possible that the OP had given just one button for an example

Comment: Yes @rv7 I see that, so we need more information from the author of the question :(

Comment: Sorry guys but i'm not good in coding.. Because I use WordPress I can not add a manual ID to the this button tag, but I really need it. When i put this code `$('.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button mejs-play button').attr('id', 'my-id');` i got this error "
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function" sorry again and thank you for answers..

Comment: Check my update that happen because of a conflit put the code inside rady function

Comment: Mohammed, (@MProduction), no, the problem is that your first block of code is wrong. `mejs-play` is A) a class, not an element type; and B) is a class on the same element as `mejs-button`. As a result, the selectors in your first code block are wrong. It should be `$('.mejs-button.mejs-playpause-button.mejs-play button')`, if you want to select for all three classes.

Comment: True @Makyen , thanks for your intervention, updated my post